# What do physicists mean when they say QM proves randomness?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, determinism, randomness

Some physicists like [Michio Kaku](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jint5kjoy6I) has said that the physics has proven randomness. Even some of my friends(they're not physicists) cite the [Delayed Choice Quantum Eraser experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delayed_choice_quantum_eraser) and entanglement to say that it proves true randomness. I've looked into the experiment quite a bit and I see no direct evidence for randomness apart from an application of probability.

If there is a consensus on randomness, is it because it for lack of a better answer, to make it easier for laymen to understand? Has true randomness been experimentally proven and is it even possible?

**References**:

- https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/why-do-scientists-claim-that-theres-true-randomness.944023/
- https://www.reddit.com/r/AskScienceDiscussion/comments/2s2ixu/does_quantum_physics_prove_that_theres_true/

Comment: *"...has said that the physics has proven randomness."* Please provide a reference for that. It's not clear what "proving randomness" means so I suspect that whatever quotation you read was somewhat more specific.

Comment: @DanielSank Well, Michio Kaku in this video https://youtu.be/Jint5kjoy6I?t=59s explains that the position of an electron is uncertain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we say that the outcome of a process is random, what we mean is that there is no way to predict the outcome exactly even if we know everything there is to know about the process and the initial state.  When the most we can possibly know is the probability of the various possible outcomes, we call it random.

What is *NOT* random is the probabilities.  Quantum mechanics can be used to calculate the probabilities of various outcomes very accurately -- which means that if we set up an experiment the same way many, many times and measure the outcomes, the ratio of the numbers of the various outcomes will almost certainly fit the quantum mechanical prediction very well- but the sequence of those outcomes in the series of experiments will be random as if determined by spinning a roulette wheel whose numbers are allocated to the various outcomes in proportion to their probabilities.

Comment: Yes, I see. But it doesn't prove that this is truly random right? From my understanding If I know the wave function of a particle and there is a probability of it being in a particular spin state when the spin is measured, couldn't you say it is only random some of the time because we actually have an incomplete model of why entanglement works.

Comment: Not quite.  Note your use of  "incomplete model" vs my use of "if we know everything there is to know about the process and the initial state".   Some might say that the essence of quantum mechanics is the uncertainty principle, which states in effect that the values of any two complementary properties of a system are only determined to within the limit set by Planck's constant.  "Determined" here means "knowable even in principle".  Nature herself does not know what the values are to greater precision.  Good terms to search are "hidden variables" and "Bell inequality".

Comment: Yeah, I know the inequalities prove that hidden variables can't be likely. But I like to think it doesn't have to be hidden variables (and i don't like the many worlds interpretation or faster than C communication). Can't it be something apart from this?

Comment: Quantum mechanical randomness fits all the relevant experimental evidence, is a simple assumption from the Ockham's Razor perspective, and makes very good theoretical and mathematical sense.  But the very idea of randomness makes a lot of people uncomfortable, maybe because we're hard-wired by evolution to seek causal, deterministic models that allow us to make accurate predictions.